# How do I pass store to the vue instance in vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

The vuex docs specify that you have to pass the created store to the vue instance like so

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store: store,
})
```

My problem is that I created a new vue project using the CLI, and that mounts the app in mian.js
using create app like so:

```
import App from './App.vue'


const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

How to I pass the store using the second method so I can acces it from any component, or how do I correctly mount the app using the first method ? What's the difference between them ?

From my understanding `createApp()` is new in vue 3, I'm not sure how it works, I can't seem to find the right docs, what's the difference between `new Vue({})` and `createApp()` ?

I'm sure I'm not understanding some basic concept, but I don't know which one...

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `createStore` from `vuex` v4 rc and then call `app.use(store)`:

store.js

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export const store = createStore({
  state () {
    return {
      count: 1
    }
  }
})
```

app.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { store } from './store'
import App from './App.vue'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(store)

app.mount('#app')
```

See [Vuex v4 installation process](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/4.0#installation-process-has-changed)

Comment: This is what I'm doing, but it still gives me an error `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function` .. I have no idea why

Comment: Fixing that gives me a store is not defined error ..

Comment: At what line of your code do you get the error `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`?

Comment: `export const store = createStore({` 
Edit: it's fixed .. I didn't import `createStore` with the curly brackets `{ }`

Comment: can you output `createStore` to console and add this output to your question?

Comment: I fix it ... it didn't work because of another dumb thing I didn't do .. thank you so much for your help.